# ffmpeg -vg -filtercomplex, create gif with color kway and limited fps

Tags: windows, ffmpeg

I need to create a gif file with color key (greenscreen) with 10FPS and specified size. I try to combine -vg and -filter_complex:

```
ffmpeg -i testdatei-c.avi -vf "fps=10,scale=320:-1:flags=lanczos" -filter_complex "[0:v]chromakey=0xFFFFFF,split[v0][v1];[v0]palettegen[p];[v1][p]paletteuse" output.gif
```

I get the error:

```
Filtergraph 'fps=10,scale=320:-1:flags=lanczos' was specified through the -vf/-af/-filter option for output stream 0:0, which is fed from a complex filtergraph.
-vf/-af/-filter and -filter_complex cannot be used together for the same stream.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All filters for a stream should be within the same filtergraph, so inside the -filter_complex

`ffmpeg -i testdatei-c.avi -filter_complex "[0:v]chromakey=0xFFFFFF,fps=10,scale=320:-1:flags=lanczos,split[v0][v1];[v0]palettegen[p];[v1][p]paletteuse" output.gif`